# Flex OLAPDataGrid Sorting

Tags: apache-flex, olap

I'm trying to provide some default sorting within the OLAPDataGrid component in Flex. There appears to be a dataCompareFunction on OLAPAttribute, but nothing I do seems to actually trigger calls to that method. Any suggestions around using this method or any others to provide sorting of the dimensions on OLAPDataGrid?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `dataCompareFunction` is not used unless the `userDataFunction` on the `OLAPAttribute` is also set (see: DefaultCubeImpl.as).

Note from edit: I guess this is the link to [DefaultCubeImpl.as](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn//opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/advancedgrids/src/mx/olap/DefaultCubeImpl.as)

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same problem. I found two passages in the Adobe Online Help. Perhaps they can help us somehow or other.

> **The order of the members, meaning the values along each dimension, is
>   based on the order in which the members appear in the flat data.** In
>   this example, the quarters appear in order of Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4
>   because the flat data was sorted by quarter. However, if the data was
>   not sorted by quarter, the members along the QuarterDim could appear
>   in any order.

Taken from [Writing a query for a simple OLAP cube](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bd4.html).

> You cannot sort columns by clicking on headers in the OLAPDataGrid
>   control. **Sorting is supported at the dimension level so that you can**
>   **change the order of members of that dimension.** Note that you can only
>   use sorting while preparing the query, and then use it to get the
>   member names displayed along the rows and column headers.

Taken from [About OLAP data grids](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bd9.html).